# Authourize tag does'nt maintain session state properly In Asp.net Core Identity ..

Tags: asp.net-core

```
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
    using HMS_Context;
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features;
    using HMS_Service.Services.MasterService;
    using HMS_Service.Services.PatientVisitService;
    using HMS_Service.UserManagementService;
    using HMS_Service.Services.PatientRegistrationService;
    using HMS_Service.Services.BloodCampService;
    using HMS_Service.Services.AccountService;
    using System;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
    using HMS_Presentation.Services;
    using HMS_Service.Services.InventoryManagementService;
    using HMS_Service.Services.SystemManagementService;
    using HMS_Service.Services.UserManagementService;
    using HMS_Service.Services.LabManagementService;
    using HMS_Service.CacheSetting.AppSettings;
    using HMS_Service.Services.BarCodeService;

    namespace HMS_Presentation
    {
        public class Startup
        {
            public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
            {
                Configuration = configuration;
            }

            public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

            // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
            public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
            {
                services.AddTransient<IAppSettings, AppSettings>();
                services.AddMemoryCache();
                services.AddOptions();
                services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));
                services.AddDbContext<_DbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
                services.AddIdentity<HMS_POCO.UserManagement.ApplicationUser, HMS_POCO.UserManagement.ApplicationRole>(
                   option => {

                       option.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
                       option.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;
                       option.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = false;

                   })
                  .AddEntityFrameworkStores<HMS_Context._DbContext>()
                  .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
                /*Cache Functionality Start*/


                /*Cache Functionality End*/



                services.AddAuthorization(options =>
                {
                    options.AddPolicy("Administrator", policy => policy.RequireRole("Admin","Superior"));
                    options.AddPolicy("Doctors", policy => policy.RequireRole("Receptionist","Doctor", "Superior"));
                    options.AddPolicy("Nurses", policy => policy.RequireRole("Nurse", "Superior"));
                    options.AddPolicy("Labortory", policy => policy.RequireRole("LabTech", "Superior"));
                    options.AddPolicy("Accountants", policy => policy.RequireRole("Accountant", "Superior")); 
                    options.AddPolicy("Receptionist", policy => policy.RequireRole("Receptionist", "Superior"));
                    options.AddPolicy("RecpDoct", policy => policy.RequireRole("Receptionist","Doctor", "Superior"));
                    options.AddPolicy("RMO", policy => policy.RequireRole("RMO", "Superior"));
                    options.AddPolicy("RD", policy => policy.RequireRole("RMO", "Doctor","Superior"));
                    // Access DNL(Doctor,Nurse ,Lab)
                    options.AddPolicy("AccessDNL", policy => policy.RequireRole("Doctor", "Nurse", "LabTech", "Superior"));

                });



                services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
                {

                    options.Cookie.Name = "YourAppCookieName";
                    options.LoginPath = "/UserAccount/Login";
                    options.LogoutPath = "/UserAccount/Logout";
                    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/UserAccount/AccessDenied";
                    options.ReturnUrlParameter = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.ReturnUrlParameter;
                });

                services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
                services.AddSession(options=>options.Cookie.HttpOnly=true);

                services.AddMvc().AddSessionStateTempDataProvider();

                services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
                services.Configure<FormOptions>(x => {
                    x.ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
                    x.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = long.MaxValue;
                    x.BufferBodyLengthLimit = long.MaxValue;
                    x.MemoryBufferThreshold = int.MaxValue;
                    x.ValueCountLimit = int.MaxValue;
                });



            }

            // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
            {
                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                    app.UseBrowserLink();

                }
                else
                {
                    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                }
                app.UseSession();
                app.UseStaticFiles();
                app.UseAuthentication();
                app.UseMvc(routes =>
                {
                    routes.MapRoute(
                        name: "default",

                        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                });
            }
        }
    }


**User Account Controller** 

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using HMS_Presentation.Services;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using HMS_Presentation.Models.AccountViewModels;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using System.Security.Claims;
using HMS_Service.UserManagementService;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using HMS_Service.Services.UserManagementService;
using HMS_POCO.UserManagement;

namespace HMS_Presentation.Controllers
{
    [Authorize(Policy = "Administrator")]   
    [Route("[controller]/[action]")]
    public class UserAccountController : Controller
    {
        private readonly UserManager<HMS_POCO.UserManagement.ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<HMS_POCO.UserManagement.ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
        private readonly RoleManager<HMS_POCO.UserManagement.ApplicationRole> _roleManager;

        //Extra Addition
        private readonly EmployeeService _employeeService;
        private readonly UserAccessLogService _userAccessLogService;
        public UserAccountController(
            UserManager<HMS_POCO.UserManagement.ApplicationUser> userManager,
            SignInManager<HMS_POCO.UserManagement.ApplicationUser> signInManager,
            IEmailSender emailSender,
            ILogger<UserAccountController> logger,
            RoleManager<HMS_POCO.UserManagement.ApplicationRole> roleManager,
            EmployeeService employeeService, UserAccessLogService userAccessLogService)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _emailSender = emailSender;
            _logger = logger;
            _roleManager = roleManager;
            _employeeService = employeeService;
            _userAccessLogService = userAccessLogService;
        }

        [TempData]
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

        [HttpGet]
        [AllowAnonymous]

        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            // Clear the existing external cookie to ensure a clean login process
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);
            ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
            return View();
        }


        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
        {
            USER_ACCESS_LOG be = new USER_ACCESS_LOG();
            be.AccessTime = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            be.UserName = model.Email;

            ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
                // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
                var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: true);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    var lookupUser = _userManager.Users.Where(c => c.UserName == model.Email).FirstOrDefault();
                    HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("UserId", lookupUser.EmpId);
                    _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
                    be.AccessedStatus = true;
                    _userAccessLogService.Add(be);
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                }
                if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
                {
                    var lookupUser = _userManager.Users.Where(c => c.UserName == model.Email).FirstOrDefault();
                    HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("UserId", lookupUser.EmpId);
                    return RedirectToAction(nameof(LoginWith2fa), new { returnUrl, model.RememberMe });
                }
                if (result.IsLockedOut)
                {
                    _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
                    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Lockout));
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                    be.AccessedStatus = false;
                    _userAccessLogService.Add(be);
                    return View(model);
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<IActionResult> LoginWith2fa(bool rememberMe, string returnUrl = null)
        {
            // Ensure the user has gone through the username & password screen first
            var user = await _signInManager.GetTwoFactorAuthenticationUserAsync();

            if (user == null)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException($"Unable to load two-factor authentication user.");
            }

            var model = new LoginWith2faViewModel { RememberMe = rememberMe };
            ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;

            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> LoginWith2fa(LoginWith2faViewModel model, bool rememberMe, string returnUrl = null)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(model);
            }

            var user = await _signInManager.GetTwoFactorAuthenticationUserAsync();
            if (user == null)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException($"Unable to load user with ID '{_userManager.GetUserId(User)}'.");
            }

            var authenticatorCode = model.TwoFactorCode.Replace(" ", string.Empty).Replace("-", string.Empty);

            var result = await _signInManager.TwoFactorAuthenticatorSignInAsync(authenticatorCode, rememberMe, model.RememberMachine);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("User with ID {UserId} logged in with 2fa.", user.Id);
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            else if (result.IsLockedOut)
            {
                _logger.LogWarning("User with ID {UserId} account locked out.", user.Id);
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Lockout));
            }
            else
            {
                _logger.LogWarning("Invalid authenticator code entered for user with ID {UserId}.", user.Id);
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid authenticator code.");
                return View();
            }
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<IActionResult> LoginWithRecoveryCode(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            // Ensure the user has gone through the username & password screen first
            var user = await _signInManager.GetTwoFactorAuthenticationUserAsync();
            if (user == null)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException($"Unable to load two-factor authentication user.");
            }

            ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;

            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> LoginWithRecoveryCode(LoginWithRecoveryCodeViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(model);
            }

            var user = await _signInManager.GetTwoFactorAuthenticationUserAsync();
            if (user == null)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException($"Unable to load two-factor authentication user.");
            }

            var recoveryCode = model.RecoveryCode.Replace(" ", string.Empty);

            var result = await _signInManager.TwoFactorRecoveryCodeSignInAsync(recoveryCode);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("User with ID {UserId} logged in with a recovery code.", user.Id);
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            if (result.IsLockedOut)
            {
                _logger.LogWarning("User with ID {UserId} account locked out.", user.Id);
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Lockout));
            }
            else
            {
                _logger.LogWarning("Invalid recovery code entered for user with ID {UserId}", user.Id);
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid recovery code entered.");
                return View();
            }
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public IActionResult Lockout()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Register(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            ViewData["RoleName"] = new SelectList(_roleManager.Roles, "Id", "Name");
            ViewData["EmployeeName"] = new SelectList(_employeeService.GetUnRegisteredEmployee(), "Id", "FirstName");
            ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
        {
            ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new HMS_POCO.UserManagement.ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email, EmpId=model.EmployeeId};
                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    IdentityRole res = await _roleManager.FindByIdAsync(model.RoleId);
                    await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, res.Name);


                    _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                }
                AddErrors(result);
            }

            ViewData["RoleName"] = new SelectList(_roleManager.Roles, "Id", "Name");
            ViewData["EmployeeName"] = new SelectList(_employeeService.GetAll(), "Id", "FirstName");
            return View(model);
        }

        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
        {
            HttpContext.Session.Clear();
            await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
            _logger.LogInformation("User logged out.");
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(HomeController.Index), "Home");
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl = null)
        {
            // Request a redirect to the external login provider.
            var redirectUrl = Url.Action(nameof(ExternalLoginCallback), "Account", new { returnUrl });
            var properties = _signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(provider, redirectUrl);
            return Challenge(properties, provider);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl = null, string remoteError = null)
        {
            if (remoteError != null)
            {
                ErrorMessage = $"Error from external provider: {remoteError}";
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Login));
            }
            var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
            if (info == null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Login));
            }

            // Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login.
            var result = await _signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey, isPersistent: false, bypassTwoFactor: true);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("User logged in with {Name} provider.", info.LoginProvider);
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            if (result.IsLockedOut)
            {
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Lockout));
            }
            else
            {
                // If the user does not have an account, then ask the user to create an account.
                ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
                ViewData["LoginProvider"] = info.LoginProvider;
                var email = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);
                return View("ExternalLogin", new ExternalLoginViewModel { Email = email });
            }
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLoginConfirmation(ExternalLoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // Get the information about the user from the external login provider
                var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
                if (info == null)
                {
                    throw new ApplicationException("Error loading external login information during confirmation.");
                }
                var user = new HMS_POCO.UserManagement.ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    result = await _userManager.AddLoginAsync(user, info);
                    if (result.Succeeded)
                    {
                        await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                        _logger.LogInformation("User created an account using {Name} provider.", info.LoginProvider);
                        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                    }
                }
                AddErrors(result);
            }

            ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
            return View(nameof(ExternalLogin), model);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ConfirmEmail(string userId, string code)
        {
            if (userId == null || code == null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(HomeController.Index), "Home");
            }
            var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
            if (user == null)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException($"Unable to load user with ID '{userId}'.");
            }
            var result = await _userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, code);
            return View(result.Succeeded ? "ConfirmEmail" : "Error");
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public IActionResult ForgotPassword()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ForgotPassword(ForgotPasswordViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
                if (user == null || !(await _userManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user)))
                {
                    // Don't reveal that the user does not exist or is not confirmed
                    return RedirectToAction(nameof(ForgotPasswordConfirmation));
                }

                // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please
                // visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532713
                var code = await _userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);
                var callbackUrl = Url.ResetPasswordCallbackLink(user.Id, code, Request.Scheme);
                await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(model.Email, "Reset Password",
                   $"Please reset your password by clicking here: <a href='{callbackUrl}'>link</a>");
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(ForgotPasswordConfirmation));
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public IActionResult ForgotPasswordConfirmation()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public IActionResult ResetPassword(string code = null)
        {
            if (code == null)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("A code must be supplied for password reset.");
            }
            var model = new ResetPasswordViewModel { Code = code };
            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ResetPassword(ResetPasswordViewModel model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(model);
            }
            var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
            if (user == null)
            {
                // Don't reveal that the user does not exist
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(ResetPasswordConfirmation));
            }
            var result = await _userManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user, model.Code, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(ResetPasswordConfirmation));
            }
            AddErrors(result);
            return View();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public IActionResult ResetPasswordConfirmation()
        {
            return View();
        }


        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult AccessDenied()
        {
            return View();
        }

        #region Helpers

        private void AddErrors(IdentityResult result)
        {
            foreach (var error in result.Errors)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
            }
        }

        private IActionResult RedirectToLocal(string returnUrl)
        {
            if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
            {
                return Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(HomeController.Index), "Home");
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

This is my code of Startup.cs file. and User Account Controller The authorize tag Does not maintain the session state properly .. Even after passing the session time the application starts without email and password required . How to fix it . i am using .NET CORE and visual studio 2017  and when i logout and then run the application it works Fine and take email and password. but without logout the account and close the tab and then run the application issue appears ...

Answer (score 0):

Use `IsPersistent=true` in default signin method mentioned below:

```
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, model.LoginPassword, true, false);
```

Here the third parameter is IsPersistent, which should be true for persistent login.

Comment: If it works, you can upvote n mark this as the answer.

Comment: The session time not out according to  the set time whenever I run my application it login's with out username and password.. @Riddhi

Comment: You need to check https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/36804.asp-net-core-mvc-authentication-and-role-based-authorization-with-asp-net-core-identity.aspx to understand identity for multiple users. Identity by default set user claims, you do not need to set any session/cookies manually.